Charger Output and Device Compatibility: A Safety Concern
The device we have has a 5V 1.5A input, and the charger has a 5V 2.5A, 9V 2A, and 12V 1.5A output.
If we use the charger at 12V 1.5A for a while and then switch to a 5V 1.5A device, could the device be damaged?

I have edited out the part of your question about what happens when you plug and unplug the PSU. This would be a usage question and would probably get your question closed. Consult the manual or specifications of the supply.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Which charger is it? Is it selectable by you what it outputs? Or is it autonegotiating USB supply perhaps, which is not a charger at all?


and the charger has a 5V 2.5A, 9V 2A, and 12V 1.5A output.

Sounds like a smart/quick charger that is able to "talk" to the target device and adjust the output accordingly. My answer will be based on this assumption.

If we use the charger at 12V 1.5A for a while and then switch to a 5V 1.5A device

That's probably not a thing you can control easily because the charger's default output voltage is 5V regardless, and if the target device supports it'll increase to 12V by the charger's control circuitry. If it doesn't then the output voltage will stay at 5V.
